# Sorting an array which the maximum value is similar to its size

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to figure out the best way to sort an array which the maximun value is similar to its size. The array does not contain repeated elements.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SortExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SortExamples sortExample = new SortExamples();

        int[] sizes = { 10000, 100000, 500000, 750000, 1000000, 1500000,
                2000000, 5000000, 7500000, 10000000, 15000000 };

        SortingMethod arraySort = new ArraySort();
        SortingMethod quickSort = new QuickSort();

        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Sorting array of length: " + sizes[i]);
            int[] array1 = sortExample.getArraySample(sizes[i]);
            int[] array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);

            assert Arrays.equals(array1, array2);

            sortExample.sort(array1, arraySort);
            sortExample.sort(array2, quickSort);

            assert Arrays.equals(array1, array2);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void sort(int[] array, SortingMethod sortingMethod) {

        assert !checkOrdered(array);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sortingMethod.sort(array);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total time with "
                + sortingMethod.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": "
                + (endTime - startTime) + " millis.");

        assert checkOrdered(array);
    }

    public int[] getArraySample(int size) {

        int[] array = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            array[i] = i;

        shuffle(array);

        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Same as java.util.Collections.shuffle(List<?>, Random)
     * 
     * @param array
     */
    public void shuffle(int[] array) {

        Random random = new Random();

        int count = array.length;

        for (int i = count; i > 1; i--)
            swap(array, i - 1, random.nextInt(i));
    }

    public boolean checkOrdered(int[] array) {

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
            if (array[i] < array[i - 1])
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static class ArraySort implements SortingMethod {

        public void sort(int[] array) {

            if (array.length < 2)
                return;

            Integer[] auxiliarArray = new Integer[getMax(array) + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                int current = array[i];
                auxiliarArray[current] = current;
            }

            int k = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < auxiliarArray.length; j++) {

                Integer current = auxiliarArray[j];

                if (current != null) {
                    array[k] = current;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }

        public int getMax(int[] array) {

            int max = array[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                if (max < array[i])
                    max = array[i];

            return max;
        }
    }

    public static class QuickSort implements SortingMethod {

        public void sort(int[] array) {
            sortInternal(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        }

        public void sortInternal(int[] array, int start, int end) {

            int i = start;
            int j = end;

            int pivot = array[(start + end) / 2];

            while (i <= j) {

                while (array[i] < pivot)
                    i++;

                while (array[j] > pivot)
                    j--;

                if (i <= j) {
                    swap(array, i, j);
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }

            int startLeft = start;
            int endLeft = i - 1;

            if (startLeft < endLeft)
                sortInternal(array, startLeft, endLeft);

            int startRigth = i;
            int endRigth = end;

            if (startRigth < endRigth)
                sortInternal(array, startRigth, endRigth);
        }
    }

    public interface SortingMethod {

        public void sort(int[] array);
    }

    public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {

        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

The output I got was:

```
Sorting array of length: 10000
Total time with ArraySort: 2 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 2 millis.

Sorting array of length: 100000
Total time with ArraySort: 14 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 16 millis.

Sorting array of length: 500000
Total time with ArraySort: 22 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 59 millis.

Sorting array of length: 750000
Total time with ArraySort: 25 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 91 millis.

Sorting array of length: 1000000
Total time with ArraySort: 33 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 122 millis.

Sorting array of length: 1500000
Total time with ArraySort: 66 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 191 millis.

Sorting array of length: 2000000
Total time with ArraySort: 100 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 278 millis.

Sorting array of length: 5000000
Total time with ArraySort: 391 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 662 millis.

Sorting array of length: 7500000
Total time with ArraySort: 2805 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 1033 millis.

Sorting array of length: 10000000
Total time with ArraySort: 3629 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 1409 millis.

Sorting array of length: 15000000
Total time with ArraySort: 3825 millis.
Total time with QuickSort: 2185 millis.
```

Is this an existing method? Could it be useful for something?

Comment: **What do you think about this way to solve it?** - Code review isn't on-topic here, you might want to take this question over to [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, Java uses quicksort. Yes, it can be useful. The problem is that your method only gives an improvement for smaller array sizes (up to 7.5mil), and only for a special type of array. Also, you don't really have a SO-compatible quesion. Your code seems to work fine...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (auto-comment from the close vote, sorry)

Comment: Have you tried [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte[]%29)?

Comment: Sorry if this was not the place. I delete the question "What do you think about this way to solve it?" I just want to know if this is an existing method and if it could be useful for something. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is a variant of [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Counting sort (`O(N+K)`) is faster than quicksort (`O(N*log(N)`) or any other sort based on comparisons (such sorts can't be faster than `O(n log(N)`), but it has limited usage.